# Rails: accessing a has_many relation from ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Is there a way to access all books of a set of authors ?
For example: Article.where(...).books that will return the associated books of selected articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a subquery:

```
Book.where(article: Article.where(...))
```

Note that Activerecord still turns this into a single SQL query:

```
 SELECT `books`.* FROM `books` WHERE `books`.`article_id` IN (SELECT `articles`.`id` FROM `articles` WHERE (...))
```